# How can zmq (zeromq) be used to send multiple requests and route async responses between two NodeJS servers?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, zeromq, messaging

I have a NodeJS API web server (let's call it WS1) that receives RESTful HTTP requests from clients, and to respond needs to first query another local server (let's call it WS2).

The flow is pretty much like this:

1. WS1 receives an HTTP request from a client and parses it.
2. WS1 sends a request to WS2 for some information.
3. When WS1 receives the response from WS2, it finishes processing the original request and sends a response back to the client.

Until now all communication between WS1 and WS2 has been done through HTTP requests, since the two machines are on the same local network.

To speed things up though I'm considering to start using [**zmq**](http://zeromq.org/) instead. I've looked at the patterns they show on the docs, but still haven't figured out a concurrency problem.

WS1 can send many requests per second to WS2, and there's no guarantee that WS2 replies in the same order as it receives the requests, since some async operations can internally take longer than others.

So, using zmq with NodeJS, how do I make sure that when WS1 receives a message from WS2 it knows to what original client request it belongs to? Is there a built-in mechanism to take care of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing some sort of "middleware" to support this functionality with zmq.

In the example below for simplicity I've used [Express](http://expressjs.com/) with [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) >= v4.0.0 (supporting native JS promises), but you can obviously substitute it with any HTTP server you like (these days I prefer [Koa](http://koajs.com/)) and promises library you prefer. This is the code for the two servers.

#### WS1 (requester)

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var mem = {};
var requester = zmq.socket('req');
requester.on("message", function(reply) {
  reply = reply.toString().split('*');
  mem[reply.pop()](reply);
});
requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");


var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var id = Date.now() + Math.random();
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    mem[id] = function (reply) {
      reply[0] === 'success' ? resolve(reply[1]) : reject(reply[1]); 
    }
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(500);
  })
  requester.send(id + '*' + message);
});

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

#### WS2 (responder)

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var responder = zmq.socket('rep');
responder.on('message', function(message) {
  message = message.split('*');
  var reqId = message[0];
  // Do whatever async stuff you need with message[1]
  // Then at the end of your callbacks you'll have something like this
  if (err) {
    responder.send('err' + '*' + JSON.stringify(err) + '*' + reqId);
  } else {
    responder.send('success' + '*' + JSON.stringify(yourData) + '*' + reqId);
  }
});
responder.bind('tcp://*:5555');
```

Answer (score 3):

0MQ is an interesting tool set that helps abstract socket communication. There are mechanism (should you choose the correct socket types) that allow the server to respond to the right client, and it is handled within the confines of 0mq.

The basic API types are:

1. PUSH-PULL
2. PUB-SUB
3. REQUEST-REPLY

IF you want to be able to have one machine respond to the originator, then I believe you want REQ-REP api type.

then you need to consider the multi-plexing on each side to get the connectors correct.  But keep it one to one for simplicity sake at first:

Sample Client (from http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:rrclient

```
// Hello World client in Node.js
// Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5559
// Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back

var zmq       = require('zmq')
  , requester = zmq.socket('req');

requester.connect('tcp://localhost:5559');
var replyNbr = 0;
requester.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('got reply', replyNbr, msg.toString());
  replyNbr += 1;
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  requester.send("Hello");
}
```

sample server (from http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:rrserver)

```
// Hello World server in Node.js
// Connects REP socket to tcp://*:5560
// Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"

var zmq = require('zmq')
  , responder = zmq.socket('rep');

responder.connect('tcp://localhost:5560');
responder.on('message', function(msg) {

  console.log('received request:', msg.toString());
  setTimeout(function() {
    responder.send("World");
  }, 1000);
});
```

The routing of the reply back to the client is handled automatically by 0MQ.  it is part of the message (although I don't remember if you see the address buffer in these examples - it maybe abstracted away).  Here is what the request envelope looks like:

[image]

it is the first frame, which allows 0MQ to be able to reply to the correct client.

Once that is running you can then consider 1..* *..1 and *..*.  All it really does is require you to change the socket types to DEALER and ROUTER where appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the awesome summary! A fundamental part related to my question is still missing though, if I understand correctly. WS1 sends messages to WS2 every time WS1 receives an HTTP request (can be many times per second). Some messages take longer than others to be processed by WS2, so the reply order is not guaranteed to be the same. When WS1 hears a message back from WS2 how can it know what original HTTP request it belongs to?

Comment: They always get delivered back to the correct client, that is part of the addressing (e.g. frame 1 in the first diagram) provided by 0mq.  If you need to gaurantee order, then you have an issue.  You will need to build that yourself

Comment: Actually looking at your code, I think I see where the confusion comes from, but then again maybe not.  So let me ask you IF the equest/reply is constrained to the GET request THEN why isn't the request connection within the GET on the client side?  That way each web request gets a different 0MQ client?  Ideally you will need to add another 0mq layer of dealer/routers.

Comment: ALSO if you want to make the distributed stuff independent from the request, you might want to use a different architecture.  I have something similar  (using Kafka instead of 0mq for a number of reasons), and I am using SOCKET.IO  to stream the results back to the browser,  Essentially a rest request from the browser to the server kicks off the process and is immediately returned to the browser.  Once the asyc process completes I stream the results back to the browser via SOCKET.IO

Comment: *why isn't the request connection within the GET on the client side?*
Because in that case it would need to establish a new connection to WS2 each time, which nullifies the purpose of using zmq, and could be served by simple HTTP interaction.

Comment: I note that you use synchronous connect, which for nodejs is surprising to me. I expect it is because async connect isn't supported for zmq nodejs -- which I find very troubling